# Highlighting a portion of a line chart in excel

Tags: pandas, linechart, xlsxwriter

I have this reproducible example below where I create a random dataframe then plot it on excel using xlsxwriter:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import xlsxwriter
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({"Start": pd.date_range("1-jan-2021", periods=72, freq="1H"),
                   'Cases': np.random.randint(0,100,size=(72))})

dates_tohighlight = list(pd.date_range("2-jan-2021", periods=10, freq="1H"))
highlighted_rows = df['Start'].isin(dates_tohighlight).map({True: 'background-color: green', False: 'background-color: grey'})
styler = df.style.apply(lambda _: highlighted_rows).set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center'})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Output2.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter') # pylint: disable=abstract-class-instantiated     
styler.to_excel(writer, sheet_name= 'Keyser',  startrow= start_row , startcol=0, index=False)
workbook = writer.book # pylint: disable=E1101
worksheet = writer.sheets['Keyser'] 

(max_rows, max_cols) = df.shape
start_row = 3 
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})
chart.add_series({
                'name' : 'Test Graph',            
                'values':    f'=Keyser!$B${start_row}:$B${max_rows+start_row}',
                'categories':     f'=Keyser!$A${start_row}:$A${max_rows+start_row}'})
chart.set_x_axis({'name': 'Timesteps', 'position_axis': 'on_tick', 'text_axis':True, 'num_font': {'rotation': -45}})
chart.set_y_axis({'name': 'Random numbers', 'major_gridlines': {'visible': False}})
worksheet.insert_chart('D3', chart, {'x_scale': 1.5, 'y_scale': 1.5})
writer.save()
```

I want to either draw two vertical lines as boundaries on the graphic to show the studied zone or  highlight that portion's background on the graphic (I'm talking about the 'dates_tohighlight' portion). Thank you !

**Edit:**

Do you think I should abandon this method & use matplotlib instead then export the image to excel (since it's possible to highlight a portion of a graph in that module ) ?

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do this. You could plot 2 additional series of 2 data points each on the chart as vertical lines to indicate the start and end points. or you could split your series in 3 and plot them on the graph with a different colour for the middle section of interest. Either way it is a little fiddly.

Comment: The first method you mentioned is what I ended up doing ... adding 2 vertical bars to my series. However, when my 'dates_tohighlight' were not continuous I had to look for the discontinuities, slice my list based on them then plot the boundaries of each sublist

Comment: Thanks for considering time to answer me though !